# I'm having problems with my pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to make a simple function to parse the arguments after an option for ex. `./a.out -p {12,14} {33,7} {4,6} --`

I want to return a `void` pointer to an array that I will later cast. The first element of the array will contain an integer defining the size. This is where my problem comes in

Starting at around line 40, I want to:

1. Define an integer `size_arr` to be the size of the arguments in between dashed options
2. Create a `void * args` and allocate 1 integer at that address.
3. Place the `size_arr` integer at the memory location of `args`
4. Change the pointer to point to the memory location after the integer, essentially making my `size_arr` value be the -1 position in my array that I am building if that makes sense.

When I examine the values in gdb (refer to screenshot below), I'm seeing that my `sizeof(int)` value is all over the place and I don't really understand why.

I finally found the correct memory location when I put `(args - (sizeof(int) - 12))`

My first thought is something to do with the fact that the memory isn't contiguous, but I'm under the impression that `malloc` does return contiguous memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    CHAR,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
} TYPE;

void *parseArgs(int argc, char *argv[], char character, TYPE t) {
    int st, fi;
    st = 0;
    fi = 0;

    // initilize to false.
    bool options[argc];
    /* Mark options that start with '-' */
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        options[i] = false;
        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
            options[i] = true;
        }
    }
    // Find range of args ie in between options
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        char *cposition = strchr(argv[i], character);
        if (st > 0 && options[i] == true) {
            fi = i;
            break;
        }
        if (options[i] == true && (character == *cposition)) {
            st = i + 1;
        }
    }
    // Define our array Size :: args ---> size of array;
    int size_arr = ((fi - st));
    void *args;
    args = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Allocate Memory for the size_arr element.
    *(int *)args = size_arr; // Set out 0th element to be equal to the size of the array;
    args = (int *)args + (sizeof(int)); // change the pointer to point the the first element after the size

    switch(t) {
      case(CHAR):
        args = malloc(size_arr * (sizeof(char)));
        for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++) {
            *((char *)args +((sizeof(char) * i))) = argv[st];
            st++;
        }
        break;
    
      case(INT):
        args = malloc(size_arr * (sizeof(int)));
        for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++) {
            *((int *)args + ((sizeof(int) * i))) = atoi(argv[st]);
            st++;
        }
        break;
    
      case(FLOAT):
        args = malloc(size_arr * (sizeof(float)));
        for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++) {
            *((float *)args + ((sizeof(float) * i))) = atof(argv[st]);
            st++;
        }
        break;
    
      case(DOUBLE):
        args = malloc(size_arr * (sizeof(double)));
        for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++) {
            *((double *)args +((sizeof(double) * i))) = atof(argv[st]);
            st++;
        }
        break;
    
      default:
        printf("Type not supported %d ... exiting\n", t);
        exit(-1);
    }
    // reset args to original address
    //(int *)args -= (sizeof(int));
    return args;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *args;
    args = parseArgs(argc, argv, 'p', INT);
    int size_arr;
    size_arr = *((int *)args - 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++) {
        printf("Argument %d: %d\n", i, *((int *)args+(sizeof(int) * i)));
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

[image: THIS IS AN IMAGE SHOWING MY DEBUGGING SESSION]

Comment: "I want to return a void pointer", so where is the `return` for that? I ask because it is so hard to find it, with your code lacking any indentation.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hey sorry about that, I return it at the end of the function, a few lines above where main starts.

Comment: You missed my point. Please apply indentation to your code, to make analysis easier for everybody, including you.

Comment: You reassign `args` multiple times, each time getting further and further away from its initial value. You also seem to want to treat `args` as a single contiguous area of memory, which is not what you have. The initial `args = malloc(sizeof(int))` will make it point to some memory. Then the consecutive assignments with `malloc` will make it point somewhere totally different and to an unrelated location. There are no connections between two calls to `malloc`. If you want a single contiguous area you need to use `realloc`.

Comment: Also note that there might be alignment problems for your different types. Especially for the (typically) 8-byte wide `double` type.

Comment: Ahhhh, i think i understand. So when I'm allocating the array, I need to use realloc. Thank you @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean allignment problems? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: A much better solution would be to return a structure containing the count (as a plain `size_t` variable) and the actual data-pointer. Then you won't have to bother with pointer arithmetic and data alignment.

Comment: That is actually a way better idea, thank you. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: A `double` being 8 bytes should be stored on 8 byte boundaries. Like `16` or `64` etc. (just made up numbers). If you store it on `4` and `12` etc. (still made up numbers) then the CPU might not be able to fetch the data optimally. Some systems might not even work at all with misaligned data.